# POST Line-based text data: text/plain

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

Currently trying to manage a website with a Python script to control IoT object.

From what I discovered, control is doing in 2 times :

- POST method to get an ID, needed to control the device.
- POST method using the ID

The first one is working with this Python script and ID is displayed in the response.

```
import requests
url = 'http://local_IP/login.cgi'
payload = {'lgname': 'theLogin', 'lgpin': 'thePin'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

For the second POST (to control the device when the user is logged in), I captured the command with Wireshark and here is the information:

> POST /user/keyfunction.cgi HTTP/1.1\r\n
>
> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\r\n
>
> Referer: http://LOCAL_IP/login.cgi\r\n

and then I have:

> Line-based text data: text/plain
>
> sess=IDReceivedWithTheFirstPOST&comm=80&Data0=2&data2=18&data1=1

So basicaly, I need a way to do a POST in Python with this "Line-based text data: text/plain" but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Hope you'll be able to help me,

Thank you,

Baptiste

EDIT: If it can help anyone someday, here is my working code:

```
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict

session = requests.Session()

url = 'http://LOCAL_IP/login.cgi'
payload = {'lgname': 'User', 'lgpin': 'Password'}

r_login = session.post(url, data=payload)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(r_login.text)

text = 'function getSession(){return'

with open('./data.txt', 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
                if line.find(text) == 1:
                        id = line.split()[2][1:17]
                        print(id)

data = OrderedDict()
data['sess']=id
data['comm']=80
data['data0']=2
data['data2']=1
data['data1']=16

url = 'http://LOCAL_IP/user/keyfunction.cgi'

r_keyfunction = session.post(url, data=data)

with open('data2.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(r_keyfunction.text)
```

Comment: Hard to tell WHERE you are getting `IDReceivedWithTheFirstPOST` from in the first get, but you can find out by printing the `r` object: `print("{}\n{}".format(r.headers, r.content))` If you show that output, I can follow up with a POST request that you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I got it from print(r.text), it's a line that looks like "function getSession(){return "randomNumber"}. I will implement a search function to extract it later, but that should not be a problem. The problem is, once I have it in a variable, to do the second POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on OPs results to use `requests.Session()`

using `requests.Session()` will capture all cookies and forward them on subsequent requests. It also pools connections and does lots of other cool things.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
payload = {'lgname': 'theLogin', 'lgpin': 'thePin'}


r_login = session.post('http://local_IP/login.cgi', data=payload)

# Figure out the ID here somehow

id_thing = 'IDReceivedWithTheFirstPOST'

payload = {
    'sess': id_thing,
    'comm': 80,
    'Data0': 2,
    'data2': 18,
    'data1': 1
}

r_keyfunction = session.post('http://local_IP/user/keyfunction.cgi', params=payload)

# do something here
```

Comment: Looks like it's not working. Second POST response is the same than the first POST when Login/password is wrong. I guess I'm "disconnected" but don't know the reason... By the way, if it can helps, the "button" on the web page that does the action I want to do with 2nd POST is this one : <button type="button" class="bo" onclick="newAJAXCommand('/user/keyfunction.cgi', cgiResponse, false,'comm=80&amp;data0=2&amp;data2=16&amp;data1=1')"><div class="bi"></div>MHS/Off</button>

Comment: Updated my original answer to use `requests.Session()`. What I usually do when trying to figure out how to programatically access a site that may have complicated requirements such as this is to run a manual loging through a proxy, like Burp. When all else fails, however, check out selenium. Sometimes a simple request won't do it, and you need an actual browser (or more specifically, a javascript VM) to successfully log in.

Comment: It's working !! Session wasn't the issue, I just had to do use OrderedDict(). The payload order wasn't respected, now it is. Thank you very much and have a nice day !